# GWT - what type of database?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

A GWT project with a few combo boxes and a button. When I click the button I need to use "if" for each combo box and depending on the answer for each one I want to get some data from a database and use it for a formula. The problem is I don't know how to create the database for the GWT project. I need to use a free one. Also maybe it is important to the question that I want to deploy the GWT project to App Engine.

I could not figure out what type of database I should use. I've read about Google Cloud SQL, but the thing**strong text** is that you have to pay for it. The other option seems to be App Engine Datastore, but I couldn't actually figure out how it should work for my project.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the App Engine documentation of different storage options:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage

Datastore on App Engine has a free quota, after which you have to pay for data and transactions.